# Use of first conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, grammaticality-in-context

We can't know for sure what will happen in the future. In this case, do we use a first conditional? For instance:

> If the weather improves, we're going to the beach. Here, we don't know wheather the weather improves or not, but if the weather improves, we are going, if not, we're not.

> If I know, I will tell you. Here, it's still uncertain that I know. Of course it doesn't guarantee it. But I know, I will tell you, if not I won't.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: What other conditional, or other grammar, do you think might be possible instead of first conditional? If we know what's confusing you, it will be easier to give you a clear answer

Comment: Is my understanding right in the above?

Comment: "We don't know _whether_ the weather _will improve_". Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @KateBunting if I'm as a commentator, which should I choose to use first conditional or second conditional? For example, there is a Arsenal vs Manchester United match today and I'm watching them. 

If Manchester United win today, it will put them in 5th place.
If Manchester United won today, it would put them in 5th place.

Comment: If the match is happening now, it would seem natural to say "If they win...".

Comment: @Jembot Have you done any research on your own about the differences between first and second conditional? Even the most basic description of them should help you decide which one to use. If you're still confused, please edit your question to tell us what specific aspect of the choice you're confused about

Comment: @KateBunting The game is happening now. But I see the writer use the second conditional. -- *Manchester City 1-0 Liverpool (53 mins) If Mancherster City won, it would put them in second place*. Why not say "If Manchester City win, it will...?"

Comment: Presumably he's not particularly confident that City will win, so he's using the 'second conditional' to refer to it as a hypothetical situation.

Comment: @KateBunting But I'm confused becuase you have said "if the match is happening now, it would seem natural to say "if they win, it will...", which one is correct?

Comment: Neither is 'more correct'; it's just that particular speaker's choice of words. As I said, _if they won it would..._ indicates slightly less confidence than _if they win it will..._

Comment: @KateBunting Well. This is live commentary, the commentator is speaking live. In the 63th minutes, England concede and Italy are a goal ahead. Now into 80 minutes. What would you use in this context -- first conditional or second conditional? *80 mins: Italy 1-0 England. If the score remains/remained how it is, England will/would be relegated to League B.*

Comment: I would probably say _remains_, but the other version isn't grammatically wrong. (I think _were to remain_ is more idiomatic than _remained_, and BTW it's **63rd**.)

Comment: @KateBunting So you would use the first conditional, wouldn't you? -- 80 mins: Italy 1-0 England. If the score remains how it is, England will be relagated to Leage B.